# Pass Array from code behind routine to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

I have a procedure in C# code-behind that reads values from several fields in a database and puts each into its own 1 dimensional array. Now I need to take those values and pass them to the client side so that I can print them out on a thermal printer.
In my code-behind I have:

```
        Public String[] PayType = new string[DetailLines];
        Public String[] PayQuantity = new string[DetailLines];
        Public String[] PayAmount = new string[DetailLines]'
        Public String Location;

       Protected Void PrintReceipt()
       *Miscellaneous code down to this point not shown.* 
        **DetailLines comes from record count**
       Location = "CA";
       PayType = new string[DetailLines];
       PayQuantity = new string[DetailLines];
       PayAmount = new string[DetailLines]'
        foreach (DataRow row in dtPOSdetail.Rows)
        {
           PayType[LineNumber] = row["fldDescription"].ToString();
           PayQuantity[LineNumber] = row["fldQuantity"].ToString();
           PayAmount[LineNumber] = string.Format("{0:C}",
           Decimal.Parse(row["fldAmount"].ToString()));
           LineNumber++;
         }
```

In my JavaScript I have:

```
var getLocation = '<%= Location %>'
var getPayType =  '<%= PayType %>'
var getPayQuantity = '<%= PayQuntity %>'
var getAmount = '<%= PayAmount %>'
```

I want to be able to do loop through the three arrays in my printer setup to establish line items.

```
request += builder.createTextElement({ data: "Location: " + GetLocation + "\\n" });
for (int i = 0; i < PayType.Length; i++)
{
   request += builder.createTextElement({ data: PayType[i] + "\\x9" + PayQuantity[i] + "\\x9" + "     " + PayAmount[i] + "\\n"});
}
```

I can print out Location but the value of each of my arrays shows as 'System.String[].  Most topics I have read on this are confusing showing the array being loaded as 'var myarray("apples", "oranges", "peaches").  I have also seen topics talking about serializing the array but that is not clear either.
Any examples of how to accomplish what I have shown would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Charles

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Razor (or your veiw engine) is calling the `ToString()` method of the object being injected into the view script.

With a string array type this produce what you are seeing:
`System.String[]`.

As javascript variable is expecting a JSON formatted object to instantiate variables, you can simply serialize to JSON your array as followed:

`var getPayType =  <%= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PayType) %>;`

Comment: Thank You!  This is exactly what I was looking forward.  Hopefully by me laying things out and your concise answer this can help someone else.